# What is the best way to display only a fragment shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am trying to make a program to just mess around with fragment shaders (mostly raymarching), similar to what websites like shadertoy and glslsandbox do, but I'm not sure how to get it set up.

I have set up a c++ sfml project and I have done some googling about the problem but haven't found a clear explanation. Some people seem to recommend drawing a rectangle that fills the screen and then setting a texture on it and using that, but is that really the best way?

Comment: *"drawing a rectangle that fills the screen"* - to execute the fragment shader you've to draw geometry. The fragment shader is executed for the fragments which are covered by the primitives of a mesh. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I guess what I'm asking is what would be the best way to draw that rectangle? Do I draw the vertices manually? Do I use the "sf::RectangleShape"? Do I need to give it a texture?

Comment: *"Do I need to give it a texture"* If the fragment shader "paints" something, then you don't need a texture at all. A texture is only needed if you want to show the texture itself or if you want to create a texture filter.

Comment: You should probably look up the docs for `sf::Shader` to see what you need, it should be documented there.

Comment: Thats like postprocessing a picture, I guess. You draw a rectangle that fills the screen. I have hard coded the 4 vertices and tex coords in the vertex shader and access them with gl_VertexID. Then you will need some input for your fragment shader which usually comes from some texture(s).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a simple `sf::RectangleShape` and then just loading the fragment shader. I found all the other answers I needed in the [sf::Shader documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shader.php#a1d7f28f26b4122959fcafec871c2c3c5).